# Rails ransack sort_link dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, ransack

I am using ransack gem in my application and I wanted to make a dropdown with possible sorting for index page.

I tried using `sort_link @query, :name`, but this creates a header that sorts `ASC` and `DESC` interchangeably.

How can I create a ransack `sort_link` that only sorts in one order, let's say `ASC`?

Comment: did you find answer? Looking for the same, and could not find info. 
<%= sort_url(@q, :created_at, default_order: :desc) %> - this will create url to sort created_at by desc but when you click it then will change for asc as you noticed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :s, t('Sort_by') %>
  <%= f.select :s, options_for_select([
        [t('Oldest'),'created_at asc'],
        [t('A-Z'),'title asc'],
        [t('Z-A'),'title desc']], params.dig(:q,:s)) %>
</div>
```